# How to create expanding summary boxes like the ones displayed for InterpolatingFunction, NearestFunction, etc.?

Tags: functions, front-end, output-formatting, elided-forms

The display forms for objects like `ClassifierFunction` are nice clickable summary boxes

[image]

I like this, and now I'm trying to create my a custom version of this for my functions, so I dissected the code in the output cell and trimmed it down to this:

```
CellPrint@
     Cell[BoxData[
       InterpretationBox[
        RowBox[{DynamicModuleBox[{Typeset`open$$ = True}, 
           PanelBox[
            PaneSelectorBox[{False -> 
               GridBox[{{PaneBox[
                   ButtonBox[
                    DynamicBox[
                     FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEBitmaps", 
                      "SquarePlusIconMedium"], 
                     ImageSizeCache -> {12., {0., 12.}}], 
                    Appearance -> None, 
                    ButtonFunction :> (Typeset`open$$ = True), 
                    Evaluator -> Automatic, Method -> "Preemptive"], 
                   Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
                   ImageSize -> 
                    Dynamic[{Automatic, 
                      3.5 (CurrentValue["FontCapHeight"]/
                        AbsoluteCurrentValue[Magnification])}]], 
                  GridBox[{{RowBox[{TagBox["\<\"Collapsed Form!\"\>", 
                        "SummaryItemAnnotation"]}]}}, 
                   BaseStyle -> {ShowStringCharacters -> False, 
                     NumberMarks -> False, PrintPrecision -> 3, 
                     ShowSyntaxStyles -> False}, 
                   GridBoxAlignment -> {"Columns" -> {{Left}}, 
                     "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}}, 
                   GridBoxItemSize -> {"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, 
                     "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}}, 
                   GridBoxSpacings -> {"Columns" -> {{2}}, 
                     "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}}]}}, AutoDelete -> False, 
                BaselinePosition -> {1, 1}, 
                GridBoxAlignment -> {"Rows" -> {{Center}}}, 
                GridBoxItemSize -> {"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, 
                  "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}}], 
              True -> GridBox[{{PaneBox[
                   ButtonBox[
                    DynamicBox[
                     FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEBitmaps", 
                      "SquareMinusIconMedium"], 
                     ImageSizeCache -> {12., {0., 12.}}], 
                    Appearance -> None, 
                    ButtonFunction :> (Typeset`open$$ = False), 
                    Evaluator -> Automatic, Method -> "Preemptive"], 
                   Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
                   ImageSize -> 
                    Dynamic[{Automatic, 
                      3.5 (CurrentValue["FontCapHeight"]/
                        AbsoluteCurrentValue[Magnification])}]], 
                  GridBox[{{RowBox[{TagBox["\<\"Open Form\"\>", 
                        "SummaryItemAnnotation"]}]}, {RowBox[{TagBox[
                        "\<\"Open Form\"\>", 
                        "SummaryItemAnnotation"]}]}, {RowBox[{TagBox[
                        "\<\"Open Form\"\>", "SummaryItemAnnotation"]}]}},
                    BaseStyle -> {ShowStringCharacters -> False, 
                     NumberMarks -> False, PrintPrecision -> 3, 
                     ShowSyntaxStyles -> False}, 
                   GridBoxAlignment -> {"Columns" -> {{Left}}, 
                     "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}}, 
                   GridBoxItemSize -> {"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, 
                     "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}}, 
                   GridBoxSpacings -> {"Columns" -> {{2}}, 
                     "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}}]}}, AutoDelete -> False, 
                BaselinePosition -> {1, 1}, 
                GridBoxAlignment -> {"Rows" -> {{Center}}}, 
                GridBoxItemSize -> {"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, 
                  "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}}]}, Dynamic[Typeset`open$$], 
             ImageSize -> Automatic], BaselinePosition -> Baseline], 
           DynamicModuleValues :> {}]}], Missing[]]], "Output", 
      ImageSize -> {350, 47}, ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, 
      ImageRegion -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

This code is a bit confusing to me and sadly many of the functions used have no documentation like DynamicBox, PanelBox, PaneSelectorBox...  Perhaps there is a more convenient way of doing this than resorting to esoteric boxes?

Comment: Related: [(55091)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55091/121), [(60292)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60292/121)

Comment: Also related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/285005/43522

Answer (score 57, accepted):

*Mathematica* does it internally by using `` BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox ``, which is quite straightforward to figure out.

#### Example

```
ClearAll[MyObject];

MyObject /: MakeBoxes[obj : MyObject[asc_? myObjectAscQ], form : (StandardForm | TraditionalForm)] := 
    Module[{above, below},
        above = { (* example grid *)
          {BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Name: ", asc["Name"]}], SpanFromLeft},
          {BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Variables: ", asc["Variables"]}], BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Length: ", asc["Length"]}]}
        };
        below = { (* example column *)
          BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Date: ", asc["Date"]}],
          BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Metadata: ", asc[MetaInformation]}]
        };
        BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[
           MyObject, (* head *)
           obj,      (* interpretation *)
           $icon,    (* icon, use None if not needed *)
           (* above and below must be in a format suitable for Grid or Column *)
           above,    (* always shown content *)
           below,    (* expandable content *)
           form,
           "Interpretable" -> Automatic
        ]
    ];
```

It is useful to define a function to test whether `MyObject` is in the correct format (and whether a summary box can be generated with no errors).

```
myObjectAscQ[asc_?AssociationQ] := AllTrue[{"Name", "Variables", "Date", "Length", MetaInformation}, KeyExistsQ[asc, #]&]
myObjectAscQ[_] = False;
```

Summary boxes typically have icons of a certain size:

```
$icon = 
  Graphics[{Red,Disk[]},
     ImageSize -> Dynamic[{ (* this seems to be the standard icon size *)
         Automatic, 
         3.5 CurrentValue["FontCapHeight"]/AbsoluteCurrentValue[Magnification]
       }]
  ];
```

Let us test it:

```
MyObject[<|
  "Name" -> "My particular object",
  "Length" -> 10,
  "Variables" -> {a,b,c},
  "Date" -> Today,
  MetaInformation -> "more info..." |>]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In its expanded form it looks like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### The `"Interpretable"` option

If `"Interpretable"` is set to `True`, the formatted object can be used directly as input, and will be interpreted as the second argument of `ArrangeSummaryBox`.

If `"Interpretable"` is set to `Automatic`, Mathematica 11.2 and later will decide whether to embed the data into the displayed form of the object based on [`$SummaryBoxDataSizeLimit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$SummaryBoxDataSizeLimit.html).  When this size is exceeded, there will be a button that can be used to embed the data.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Usage

Let us define a property retrieval interface, so out `MyObject` actually does something:

```
MyObject[asc_?AssociationQ][prop_] := Lookup[asc, prop]
```

Let's copy-paste the formatted object from above as new input:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is this a v10 only feature?

Comment: @Quantum I don't think so, as this type of object-representation is certainly older than v8. However, I cannot test it as I only have v10; perhaps someone cares to add this information.

Comment: I modernized the answer. Everything shown here should work in versions 10.0+ and is current as of 11.2.  This is partly based on the implementation found in built-in packages, so this method of defining summary boxes should be safe.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Szabolcs, this greatly enhanced the post!

Comment: It appears that "Interpretable"-> Automatic is not supported on older versions of Mathematica (although "Interpretable" -> True is). For example, with 10.4.1 on macOS I get extra symbols EllisionsDump`typedHead, EllisionsDump`leftBracket, and EllisionsDump`rightBracket in the output along with the expected formatted output. The default with 12.1 is "Interpretable" -> Automatic anyway, so it is best for backwards compatibility to not specify this option.

Answer (score 28):

The following shows a way to emulate the summary boxes using only documented constructs:

```
grid[g_] := 
 Column[Row /@ MapAt[Style[#, Gray] &, g, Table[{i, 1}, {i, Length[g]}]]]

foo /: MakeBoxes[c : foo[___], form : (StandardForm | TraditionalForm)] := 
 With[{boxes = 
    RowBox[{"foo", "[", 
      ToBoxes[Panel[
        OpenerView[
         {grid[{{"Something: ", 1}, {"Other: ", 2}}], 
          grid[{{"Extra: ", 3}}]}
        ], 
        BaselinePosition -> Baseline], 
       form], "]"}]
    }, 
    InterpretationBox[boxes, c]
 ]

foo[]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is a simplified version of something I used in practice.

It only makes sense to use this if you have some sort of requirement to only use documented functions.

---

If you do this, do not forget to also provide a nice OutputForm, which will be automatically used when running Mathematica in command line mode.  It can be done like this:

```
Format[foo[___], OutputForm] := "foo[<>]"
```

Answer (score 18):

> Perhaps there is a more convenient way of doing this than resorting to esoteric boxes.

The following uses the code you posted to define a function:

```
summaryDisplay = DynamicModule[{open = True, 
  sqrplus = RawBoxes@FrontEndResource["FEBitmaps", "SquarePlusIconMedium"],
  sqrminus = RawBoxes@FrontEndResource["FEBitmaps", "SquareMinusIconMedium"],
  paneF = Pane[Button[Dynamic[#, ImageSizeCache -> {12., {0., 12.}}], 
      open = #2, Appearance -> None, Evaluator -> Automatic,  Method -> "Preemptive"], 
     Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
     ImageSize -> Dynamic[{Automatic, 3.5 (CurrentValue["FontCapHeight"]/
           AbsoluteCurrentValue[Magnification])}]] &,
  gridF1 = Grid[#, BaseStyle -> {ShowStringCharacters -> False, 
       NumberMarks -> False, PrintPrecision -> 3, ShowSyntaxStyles -> False}, 
     Alignment -> {{{Left}}, {{Automatic}}}, 
     ItemSize -> {{{Automatic}}, {{Automatic}}}, 
     Spacings -> {{{2}}, {{Automatic}}}] &,
  gridF0 = Grid[{{##}}, AutoDelete -> False, BaselinePosition -> {1, 1}, 
     Alignment -> {{{Center}}}, ItemSize -> {{{Automatic}}, {{Automatic}}}] &}, 
 Panel[PaneSelector[{False -> 
   gridF0[paneF[sqrplus, True], gridF1[{Row[{#}]} & /@ #]], 
  True -> gridF0[paneF[sqrminus, False], 
    gridF1[{Row[{#}]} & /@ #2]]}, Dynamic[open], 
 ImageSize -> Automatic], BaselinePosition -> Baseline, 
ImageSize -> {200, Automatic}, ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}], 
DynamicModuleValues :> {}] &;
```

Example:

```
summaryDisplay[{"ClosedForm"}, {"OpenForm", "OpenForm", "OpenForm"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

The following solution is slightly more general than @Istvàn's answer, and also fixes the icon-size to what seems to be the standard.

First, we define

```
ClearAll[summaryForm];
summaryForm[name_, icon_, infos_, maxInfos_, form_, expr_] := RawBoxes@Quiet@Check[
  Module[{shown, hidden},
    (* convert info-table into summary items *)
    {shown, hidden} = Map[BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[#, form]&, TakeDrop[infos, maxInfos], {2}];
    (* arrange the summary and make sure the label is gray (therefore StyleBox) *)
    StyleBox[BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[
      name, 
      expr,
      Deploy@Show[icon, 
        (* avoid gray background before mouse-over *)
        Background -> White, 
        (* set standard image size *)
        ImageSize -> Dynamic[{
          Automatic, 
          3.5 CurrentValue["FontCapHeight"]/AbsoluteCurrentValue[Magnification]
        }]
      ],
      shown,
      hidden,
      form,
      (* formatted object should be uasable as input *)
      "Interpretable" -> True
    ], "NonInterpretableSummary"]
  ],
  (* in case something goes wrong *)
  ToBoxes@Panel@Short[expr]
]
```

Now you can specify automatic formatting for your own function, using

```
Format[testfunction[x_], StandardForm] := summaryForm[
  "testfunction",
   Graphics[{Circle[], Disk[{0,0},1,{0,x}]}],
  {{"Even: ",EvenQ[x]},{"Value: ",x},{"Prime: ",PrimeQ[x]}},2,
  StandardForm,
  x
]
```

The last argument `x` is how the summary should be interpreted, so in the more general case you may want to replace it by something like `testfunction[x]`.

Then `testfunction` is displayed as

```
testfunction[2]
```

[image: testfunction summary panel]

And of course you can use it as input, and the opener works as expected:

[image: testfunction summary panel in equation]

```
(* -15 *)
```

Using `summaryForm` it does not matter how your object is structured internally, and, once defined, you can use it to create many different kinds of formatted objects with very little additional code.

Since this Q&A is a bit hard to find if you don't know how this feature is called, I mention a few more functions which have these summary panels: `InterpolatingFunction`, `TimeSeries`, `EventSeries`, `DataDistribution`.

Comment: Thanks for this. One problem I ran into when defining a `Format` for a function with a `::usage` message and info that uses `Part` is that `?` throws an `Part::partd -- Part specification StandardForm[Short[Shallow[HoldForm[in[[1]]], {10, 50}], 5]] is longer than depth of object.` error. In this case, extra `Quiet`s in the `SummaryForm` call fixed it. Just putting this here in case someone else runs into this issue.