# How to mimic thing["property"] syntax?

Tags: programming, associations, object-oriented, elided-forms

Many builtin "things" support the (usually undocumented) syntax thing["property"], and usually the available properties can be listed using thing["Properties"] (thing["Methods"] might work too).

Examples include InterpolatingFunction, FittedModel, DateObject, a lot of mesh region stuff and FEM stuff.

These symbols act essentially like objects, used only as arguments to other functions that access their properties (e.g. `PredictorFunction`), or whose properties are accessible with `DownValue` syntax (e.g. `ClassifierMeasurements`).

Moreover, these functions, like `PredictorFunction[]` are returned with this frequently encountered `DisplayForm`:

[image]

These *"object-like"* symbols are typically (nested) `Associations` wrapped in their symbol, the `FullForm` of the PredictorFunction above is:

```
PredictorFunction[Association[Rule["Basic",Association[Rule["ExampleNumber",4],Rule["FeatureNumber",1],Rule["ScalarFeature",True]]],Rule["CommonFeaturePreprocessor",MachineLearning`PackageScope`Preprocessor["InputMissing",List[List[4]]]],Rule["PredictionPreprocessor",MachineLearning`PackageScope`Preprocessor["Standardize",List[5.25`,2.7233557730613653`]]],Rule["ProbabilityPostprocessor",Identity],Rule["Combiner",MachineLearning`PackageScope`Combiner["First"]],Rule["Decision",Association[Rule["Prior",Automatic],Rule["Utility",Function[DiracDelta[Plus[Slot[2],Times[-1,Slot[1]]]]]],Rule["Threshold",0],Rule["PerformanceGoal",Automatic]]],Rule["Models",List[Association[Rule["Method","LinearRegression"],Rule["Theta",List[List[0.`],List[0.9954921542867711`]]],Rule["DistributionData",List[NormalDistribution,List[0.11611695002854867`]]],Rule["L1Regularization",0],Rule["L2Regularization",0.00001`],Rule["ExtractedFeatureNumber",1],Rule["FeatureIndices",List[1]],Rule["FeaturePreprocessor",MachineLearning`PackageScope`Preprocessor["Sequence",List[MachineLearning`PackageScope`Preprocessor["Standardize",List[List[4.`],List[Times[2,Power[Rational[5,3],Rational[1,2]]]]]],MachineLearning`PackageScope`Preprocessor["PrependOne"]]]]]]],Rule["FeatureInformation",List[Association[Rule["Name","feature1"],Rule["Type","Numerical"],Rule["Sparsity",0.`],Rule["Quantiles",List[1,1,1,3,3,5,5,7,7]]]]],Rule["PredictionInformation",Association[Rule["Quantiles",List[2.`,2.`,2.`,4.5`,4.5`,6.`,6.`,8.5`,8.5`]],Rule["Name","value"],Rule["Sparsity",0.`]]],Rule["Options",List[Rule[Method,List[Rule[List[1],List["LinearRegression",Rule["L1Regularization",0],Rule["L2Regularization",0.00001`]]]]]]],Rule["Log",Association[Rule["TrainingTime",0.039456`],Rule["MaxTrainingMemory",186792],Rule["DataMemory",424],Rule["FunctionMemory",8936],Rule["LanguageVersion",List[10.1`,0]],Rule["Date","Tue 11 Aug 2015 18:32:58"],Rule["ProcessorCount",4],Rule["ProcessorType","x86-64"],Rule["OperatingSystem","MacOSX"],Rule["SystemWordLength",64],Rule["Events",List[Association[Rule["Event","ParseData"],Rule["StartTime",0.000109`2.1879414957726175],Rule["ElapsedTime",0.000446`],Rule["MaxMemoryUsed",15176],Rule["StartMemory",3096],Rule["EndMemory",4144]],Association[Rule["Event","TrainModel"],Rule["StartTime",0.001426`3.3046345233478402],Rule["ElapsedTime",0.037726`],Rule["MaxMemoryUsed",164080],Rule["StartMemory",9096],Rule["EndMemory",13824]]]]]]]]
```

How can I recreate this sort of functionality with my own objects and functions? ***Are there any methodologies for writing down-values of symbols like this?***

**Example:**

Here's a mini demo of what I'm talking about:

```
c = note[<|"Pitch"->pitch[0],"Duration"->1|>];
e = note[<|"Pitch"->pitch[4],"Duration"->1|>];
g = note[<|"Pitch"->pitch[7],"Duration"->1|>];
cc = chord[<|"Notes"->{c,e,g}|>];
```

I'd have to do something ugly like this:

```
In[2]:= c_chord[property_String] := (c[[1]])[property]
```

To get this to work:

```
In[3]:= cc["Notes"]
Out[3]= {note[<|"Pitch" -> pitch[0], "Duration" -> 1|>], 
 note[<|"Pitch" -> pitch[4], "Duration" -> 1|>], 
 note[<|"Pitch" -> pitch[7], "Duration" -> 1|>]}
```

Comment: There are 55 in V9, before Association.

Comment: I see, but that doesn't mean they weren't using some internal version right? The question is still interesting to me, if there is now a standard accepted way that wolfram internally does object orientation.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16869/5 and this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54493/5?

Comment: I don't think these have anything to do with object oriented programming.  People have simply found it appropriate to name things "*Object" in a few different and unrelated contexts.  Like `DateObject`.  It could just as well be `DateExpression`.

Comment: Marginally related: many builtin "things" support the (usually undocumented) syntax `thing["property"]`, and usually the available properties can be listed using `thing["Properties"]` (`thing["Methods"]` might work too).  Examples include `InterpolatingFunction`, `FittedModel`, `DateObject`, a lot of mesh region stuff and FEM stuff, etc.

Comment: IMO the answer is "none of the above". *Mathematica* does not extensively use object oriented code for anything at the top level. Individual packages may or may not use some ideas from this general area, but rarely (never?) do they provide a full object hierarchy, inheritance, etc. Also, I have to say, many of your questions are becoming very abstract and speculative lately. If you could make them more concrete I suspect they would be able to attract more attention. I'm voting to close this one since I really can't imagine what an "ideal" answer should actually contain.

Comment: To the closers: I realized the wording was confused, I have tweaked the question's text... Hopefully this makes it clear and concrete.

Comment: I saw your comment before I cast my vote. Now I voted to leave it open. Thanks for clarifying the question.

Comment: With respect to how the short output form looks, have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77658)?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. that explains how to make the nice boxes, I love that answer! but then when writing the downvalues to access the properties, not sure what the best solution is... see the example I added.

Comment: @Szabolcs I used your comment as the first sentence, exactly what I was trying to say, hop you don't mind!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How can I recreate this sort of functionality with my own objects and functions? Are there any methodologies for writing down-values of symbols like this?

If you want to know how to get a similar output format, here's a silly toy example:

```
(* The icon isn't really that important *)
icon = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -5, 5}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True,
  ImageSize -> Dynamic[{Automatic, 3.5 (CurrentValue["FontCapHeight"] / AbsoluteCurrentValue[Magnification])}],
  GridLines -> None, FrameTicks -> None, AspectRatio -> 1,
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Thickness[Tiny], RGBColor[0.368, 0.507, 0.71]]];

(* SummaryItemAnnotation and SummaryItem are the styles used in the labels *)
label[lbl_, v_] := Row[{Style[lbl <> ": ", "SummaryItemAnnotation"], Style[ToString[v], "SummaryItem"]}];

(* Set up formatting *)
BigStupidFunction /: MakeBoxes[ifun : BigStupidFunction[s1_, s2_, hs1_, hs2_], fmt_] :=
BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[
  BigStupidFunction, ifun, icon,
  {label["Some stuff", s1], label["Other stuff", s2]},
  {label["Hidden stuff 1", hs1], label["Hidden stuff 2", hs2]},
  fmt
];
```

Now the output format of `BigStupidFunction` will be nicely boxed up like `InterpolatingFunction`.

[image]

Comment: wow, love your color theme!

Comment: Can you plz post your style sheet? :)

Comment: [Here you go](https://goo.gl/xqvDku)

Comment: @M.R. or @rhennigan: Does/did this implement the desired idiom as it seems somewhat different from `PredictorFunction`? For example, the `FullForm` of `PredictorFunction` contains not just the appearance related to `BoxForm\`ArrangeSummaryBox` but also other information about, and for the running of, the model - a feature that would seem fundamental to this object-like approach?

Comment: @rhennigan Can you please post your stylesheet again? :-)