# How to set a property in an object with association syntax?

Tags: associations, object-oriented

I have a simple object orientation example [using this solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91327/how-does-thingproperty-syntax-work/91434?noredirect=1#comment248520_91434):

```
MyObject[assn_Association][args__String] := assn[args]
initMyObject[assn_Association] := With[{a = Merge[{assn, <|"SomeProperty"->2|>}, First]}, MyObject[assn]]
```

You can create the object:

```
In[1]:= o = initMyObject[<|"a" -> 1|>]
Out[1]= MyObject[<|"a" -> 1|>]
```

You can access the object:

```
In[2]:= o["a"]
Out[2]= 1
```

And it looks like you can assign:

```
In[3]:= o["SomeProperty"] = 22
Out[3]= 22
```

But it doesn't work:

```
In[4]:= FullForm @ o
Out[4]= MyObject[Association[Rule["a",1]]]
```

Is there a way to make this syntax (`obj["property"] = value`) work here?

**Update**

I thought I could so something like this:

```
MyObject /: Set[m_MyObject[arg_String], val_] := Set[m, alteredCopy[m,<|arg->val|>]]
```

but this an other variants doesn't work...

Comment: What about this answer? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/116595/5478