# Nested association values validation. POJsO handling

Tags: pattern-matching, associations, guidelines

Sometimes it is convenient to work in your package/app with "objects" like:

```
childObject = <|
  "id" -> 284,
  "text" -> "texttext",
  "property" -> <|
    "type" -> "String",
    "content" -> "test"
    |>
  |>

object = <|
  "id" -> 1,
  "name" -> "name1",
  "subobjects" -> {
    childObject
    }
 |>
```

But if you want to pass them around you have to be able to validate a structure of them easily etc etc. E.g. `f[object_Association]` is not enough.

Basically **this question asks about neat implementation of basic "methods" neeeded for them**. Which methods? I don't know yet but at least:

- construction from inherited "class" + a few changed values
- validating a minimal structure of an object (precise or not)
- validating an exact structure
- ...

---

I've started with validating a minimal structure:

```
childObjectPattern = KeyValuePattern@{
    "id" -> _Integer,
    "text" -> _String,
    "property" -> KeyValuePattern[{
       "type" -> _String,
       "content" -> _String
    }]
};

objectPattern = KeyValuePattern@{
    "id" -> _Integer,
    "name" -> _String,
    "subobjects" -> {childObjectPattern ...}
};
```

That's convenient, isn't it?

```
MatchQ[object, objectPattern]
```

> True

But I need precision and I need to know where it doesn't match

```
childObject = <|  "id" -> 284,  "text" -> "texttext",
  "property" -> <|    "type" -> 1,    "content" -> "test"    |>
|>;

object = <|"id"->1, "name"->"name1", "subobjects"->{childObject}|>;
```

but `MatchQ` won't tell us that the "property" "type" of a `childObject` is incorrect. Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
ClearAll[match];

match[expr_, kvp_KeyValuePattern] := Merge[
   {expr, Association @@ kvp}, Apply[match]
];
match[
  expr : {___}, 
  {Thread[ Verbatim[Repeated | RepeatedNull], Alternatives][kvp_KeyValuePattern, ___]}
] := match[#, kvp] & /@ expr;

match[expr_, kvp : Except[_KeyValuePattern]] := MatchQ[expr, kvp]
```

---

```
match[object, objectPattern]
```

> ```
> <|
>     "id" -> True, 
>     "name" -> True, 
>     "subobjects" -> {
>       <|
>          "id" -> True, 
>          "text" -> True, 
>          "property" -> <|
>            "type" -> False, 
>            "content" -> True
>          |>
>       |>}
>  |>
> ```

```
Position[%, False]
```

> ```
> {{Key["subobjects"], 1, Key["property"], Key["type"]}}
> ```

Perfect!

In case where the initial set of questions is to broad:

- Can `match` be improved/compactified?
- Currently it doesn't care about keys that aren't present in patterns, but what should I do to make it checking *exact* structure. Replacing `KeyValuePattern` with `Association` will make them order dependent, which is not what I want.

#### The key is brevity.

Comment: "The key is brevity." ← What if you have a complex machinery that does the matching based on a simple pattern?

Comment: @Szabolcs The best would be to have a 10 lines of code I can just paste whenever I need it. But I think I can live with a bigger package as long as it isn't affecting so much the straightforward coding style presented here. I'm not sure if I'm clear :)

Answer (score 7):

## General

The real problem with objects is that sooner or later you really start to want some of the fields mutable. And once you want it, you really open a can of worms. Also, for methods, you will find very soon that you want some nice features such as pattern-based method overloading and the syntax similar to how we use functions in Mathematica. I do have a full-fledge object-oriented extension for M (yet another one!) in the works, and plan to publish it very soon. While it started brief, it is no longer.

In any case, I will try to provide an answer that would be close to the spirit of what you presumably are after.

## Validation

Your `match` function looks pretty good. I will provide a slightly modified version below, but generally I don't see away to vastly improve it. Here is a modified version:

```
ClearAll[match, Matched];

$multiPattern = Thread[Verbatim[Repeated|RepeatedNull],Alternatives];

match[expr_,kvp_KeyValuePattern]:=
  Merge[{expr,Association @@ kvp},Apply[match]];

match[expr:{___},{$multiPattern[kvp_KeyValuePattern,___]}]:=
  match[#,kvp]& /@ expr;

match[expr_,kvp:Except[_KeyValuePattern]]:=
  Matched[MatchQ[expr,kvp]];

match[arg_]:=Matched[False];
```

Below is the function `validate`, which is the one I suggest to use, and which has an operator form. It is more precise than just `match` in two ways: it only looks for `match` failures in a form `Matched[False]` (thus excluding false negatives from free-hanging `False` in an expression), and it also disallows keys which are present in the pattern and not present in the object, and vice versa.

```
ClearAll[validate];
validate[patt_]:=Function[expr, validate[expr, patt]];

validate[expr_, patt_]:=
    FreeQ[match[expr, patt], Matched[False]];
```

## Inheritance

I will try to answer the inheritance part, by providing a micro-framework that would add the support for it in what I think is a minimally intruding way.

### Implementation

Here is the code:

```
ClearAll[DefType, DefMethod, Object, SuperType, ObjectQ, New, $types, TypeQ, Extends, MsgFail];

Object::nomethod = "Object type has no method `1`";
Object::invld = "Object `1` is not a valid object";

SetAttributes[MsgFail, HoldFirst];
MsgFail[mn_MessageName, args___]:= (Message[mn, args]; $Failed);

$types = <|Object -> True|>;

TypeQ[type_Symbol]:= KeyExistsQ[$types, type];

SuperType[Object] = Null;
SuperType[_] = Object;

ObjectQ[Object[assoc_Association]]:=ObjectQ[assoc];
ObjectQ[assoc_Association]:=
  KeyExistsQ[assoc, "Type"] && TypeQ[assoc["Type"]];
ObjectQ[_]=False;

GetType[Object[assoc_Association]?ObjectQ]:=assoc["Type"];
GetType[_]:=$Failed;

ObjectValidQ[o:Object[assoc_Association]?ObjectQ]:=
  Validator[GetType[o], KeyDrop[assoc,"Type"]];
ObjectValidQ[_]=False;

New[__]:=$Failed

SetAttributes[DefType, HoldFirst];
DefType[type_Symbol, validator_, clear_:True]:=
  Module[{},
    If[clear,ClearAll[type]];
    type /: Validator[type, assoc_Association]:=
      validator[assoc];
    type /: Validator[type, _]:=False;
    type /: New[type, assoc_Association]:= 
      With[{validated = validator[assoc]},
        Object[Append[assoc, "Type" -> type]] /; validated
      ];
    AppendTo[$types, type -> True];
    type
];

DefType[type_Symbol ~ Extends ~ super_Symbol?TypeQ, validator_]:=
  Module[{},
    ClearAll[type];
    type /: SuperType[type] = super;
    DefType[type, validator, False]
  ];    

DefMethod /: 
  SetDelayed[
    DefMethod[type_?TypeQ][method_Symbol[args___]],
    rhs_
  ]:=
    Module[{},
      If[DownValues[method] === {},
        method[Super, l___,o_Object?ObjectQ, r___ ]:=
          method[SuperType[GetType[o]], l, o, r];
        method[l___, o_Object?ObjectValidQ, r___] /; !MatchQ[{l},{Super | _?TypeQ,___}]:=
          method[GetType[o], l, o, r];
        method[___,o_Object,r___]/;!MatchQ[{l},{Super | _?TypeQ,___}]:=
          MsgFail[Object::invld, o];
        method[t_Symbol?TypeQ, argums___]:=
          method[SuperType[t], argums];
        method[Object,___]:=MsgFail[Object::nomethod, method]
      ];
      type /: method[type, args]:=rhs;
    ];
```

### Usage

#### Creating an object

Let me illustrate how you can use it. First, we define a simple `Person` type:

```
DefType[Person, 
  validate[KeyValuePattern[{
    "FirstName" -> _String,
    "LastName" -> _String
  }
]]]

(* Person *)
```

Let us now create an object:

```
p = New[Person, <|"FirstName" -> "John", "LastName" -> "Smith"|>]
New[Person, <|"FirstName" -> "John", "SurName" -> "Smith"|>]

(*
   Object[<|"FirstName" -> "John", "LastName" -> "Smith", "Type" -> Person|>]

   $Failed
*)
```

The second attempt failed, since the object info did not pass validation. Note that the object construction is a simple process of validation plus adding a special field "Type". This field is reserved and should not be used as an info field.

#### Defining methods

Let us now define some methods:

```
ClearAll[getInfo, getLastName, getFirstName]
DefMethod[Person] @ getFirstName[_[assoc_]] := assoc["FirstName"];

DefMethod[Person] @ getLastName[_[assoc_]] :=assoc["LastName"];

DefMethod[Person] @ getInfo[o_] :=
  StringJoin["Name: ", getFirstName[o], "  ", getLastName[o]];
```

and use them:

```
getInfo[p]

(* "Name: John  Smith" *)
```

On an invalid object, the method will automatically fail:

```
getInfo[Object[ <|"FirstName" -> "John", "SurName" -> "Smith"|>]]
```

> ```
>  During evaluation of In[674]:= Object::invld: Object Object[<|FirstName->John,SurName->Smith|>] is not a valid object
> ```

```
(* $Failed *)
```

#### Inheritance

Let us now create a subtype of `Person`:

```
DefType[Employee ~ Extends ~ Person, 
  validate[KeyValuePattern[{
    "FirstName" -> _String,
    "LastName" -> _String,
       "EmployeeInfo" -> KeyValuePattern[{
          "Company" -> _String,
          "Department" -> _String
       }]
    }]]
]

(* Employee *)
```

Now let us create an instance:

```
john = New[Employee,
  <|"FirstName" -> "John", "LastName" -> "Smith", 
    "EmployeeInfo" ->
      <|
        "Company" -> "Microsoft",
        "Department" -> "Sales"
      |>
  |>
]

(* Object[<|"FirstName" -> "John", "LastName" -> "Smith", "EmployeeInfo" -> <|"Company" -> "Microsoft", "Department" -> "Sales"|>, "Type" -> Employee|>] *)
```

We can still use the methods of the super-type:

```
getInfo[john]
getFirstName[john]

(* 
   "Name: John  Smith"
   "John"
*)
```

Suppose now that you want to redefine the `getInfo` method, so that it also tells us about the employment - related info for `john`:

```
DefMethod[Employee] @ getInfo[o : Object[assoc_]] :=
  StringJoin[
    getInfo[Super, o],
    "; Company: ", assoc["EmployeeInfo"]["Company"],
    "; Department: ", assoc["EmployeeInfo"]["Department"]
  ]
```

And now:

```
getInfo[john]

(* "Name: John  Smith; Company: Microsoft; Department: Sales" *)
```

As you can see, it works as we want, and also, you still have an access to the method of the supertype, by using the `method[Super, args]` form.

## Summary

I presented a mini-framework that adds stronger typing and inheritance to immutable objects based on `Association`. It is really minimal, but hopefully still provides basic common tools, such as type-checking, object validation in method calls, inheritance and method overrides in subtypes. It can be further extended to incorporate other features.

I didn't have the time to thoroughly test the code, so it could contain a number of bugs (I am sure it does).

Comment: Don't bother answering if this was too long ago but maybe you recall what is the point of `validate` if one can just `MatchQ[expr, patt]`?

Comment: @Kuba A cursory look at the code above suggests that `MatchQ` might not be ideal, because `KeyValuePattern` is somewhat permissive. The `match` function above, performs stricter matching, and `validate` simply inspects the result of `match` for failures. Also, `validate` can easily be modified to provide a more detailed information about the parts that didn't match, which I didn't do here, but which was your original motivation for `match`.

Comment: @Kuba The funny thing is that I completely forgot about this answer, which actually looks quite useful also for some of the things I do.

Comment: Yes it does, and thanks for the comment. I need it for my lightweight error handling. I needed to modify `$multiPattern` because currently it matches `{}` with `Repeated` which should not happen. And since I'm on it I will probably add `Matched[Missing]` to the family.

Comment: @Kuba Sounds good. Feel free to edit my answer and add your changes.