# CompiledFunction showing its contents

Tags: output-formatting, compile

`CompiledFunction`s usually appear very compactly, for instance:

```
comp = With[{d1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}},
  Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{y},
    y = x^2;
    d1.x + y]
   ]
  ]
```

[image]

However, sometimes this gets "unpacked". One obvious way is:

```
FullForm[comp]
```

However this also does it:

```
Hold[Evaluate[comp]] // Replace[#1, {Hold[x_] :> x}, Infinity] &
```

> Hold[CompiledFunction[{10, 11., 
>      5468}, {{_Real, 1}}, {{3, 1, 0}, {3, 1, 
>       4}}, {{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {2, 2, 2}}, {12, {2, 0, 1}}, {3, {2, 0, 
>        0}}}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 
>      5}, {{40, 56, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1}, {42, "CoerceTensor", 2, 0, 0, 2, 
>       2, 2, 3, 2, 3}, {42, "Dot", 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 
>       4}, {44, 4, 1, 4}, {1}}, 
>     Function[{x}, Module[{y\$}, y$ = x^2; {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}.x + y$]], 
>     Evaluate]]

Why is this? There is no `Hold` in the original expression for this to act on.

Furthermore, if we replace the levelspec `Infinity` by `All` (side question: what is the difference? `All` doesn't seem to be documented in this case), it doesn't unpack.
And if we replace `d1` by e.g. `3.` and the `Dot` by multiplication, or get rid of `d1` entirely, it also doesn't unpack.

Is this a bug (I'm using "11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)"), or can I find somewhere under what conditions this happens?

(The line of code above is useless ofcourse, but in reality instead of `comp` I have a bigger expression, that includes something like `comp`, that is being put together. The "unpacked" form of the `CompiledFunction` still works, but makes the code unreadable.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has to do, AFAIR, with whether the expression is marked internally as "evaluated" or perhaps "valid object."  If it is so marked, it will be typeset by the Front End in the [summary-box](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77658/how-to-create-expanding-summary-boxes-like-the-ones-displayed-for-interpolatingf) way; if it is not evaluated (or not valid), you will get the input form.  This happens for other functions besides `CompiledFunction`, too.  I don't believe there is a way at the user level to access the flag(s) that indicate the "evaluated" status of an expression. @WReach's [`traceView*` functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29340/4999) seem to infer it from the evaluation sequence and marks them *`"inert"`*, if you wish to explore the difference between `Hold[Evaluate[comp]]` and `Hold[Evaluate[comp]] // Replace[#1, {}, Infinity] &`.

What seems to happen is that when `Replace` scans the expression, it must do something that marks the expression as needing reevaluation, even if it does nothing:

```
Hold[Evaluate[comp]] // Replace[#1, {}, Infinity] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In fact, in the case in question, any level specification of `5` or higher triggers the behavior:

```
Hold[Evaluate[comp]] // Replace[#1, {}, {5}] &
```

To get the summary box back, the `CompiledFunction` needs to be reevaluated.  One way is with the following replacement:

```
Hold[Evaluate[comp]] // Replace[#1, {}, {5}] &
% /. cf_CompiledFunction :> Evaluate@cf /; True
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here's the same thing applied to `InterpolatingFunction`:

```
ifn = Interpolation[N@Range[4]^2];
Hold[Evaluate[ifn]] // Replace[#1, {}, Infinity] &
% /. f_InterpolatingFunction :> Evaluate@f /; True
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here are the outputs of `traceView2[]` on the two examples.  The important difference is in the second-to-last line, which shows whether the `CompiledFunction` is marked *`"inert"`* or not:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: At least some of these flags may be tested with ``System`Private`NoEntryQ`` and ``System`Private`ValidQ`` (there is also ``System`Private`MDataQ`` but I've never used it).

Comment: The relevant flag is `ValidQ`. Just tested.

Comment: @b3m2a1 How did you test it?  It does not work for me....I mean it does test if the expression is, say, a valid `CompiledFunction`, but it does not test if it is "inert."  It's the "evaluated" status that is relevant to the Q in the OP.

Comment: My guess is you need to use ``System`Private`HoldValidQ``. See also my answer for some more details.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thanks, I got it. I needed to mimic the `MakeBoxes` code. (+1) -- There still seem to be distinct "valid" and "evaluated" flags; or the "valid" flag has more than two states (e.g. `True`, `False`, `Evaluate`).  For instance `foo = CompiledFunction[a, b, c]` generates an error but re-executing `foo` does not. -- Also, while `Replace` unpacks the instance of `d1` in the compiled code, if I unpack it directly, the expression is still valid. There do not seem to be other packed arrays in `comp`, none that I can find at least.

Comment: yeah this is certainly the case. That “is it completely evaluated” flag is simply one that we can’t test for I think. My sense is that a lot of the functions that are both head and constructor (like `CompiledFunction`) use a flag like `ValidQ` or `NoEntryQ` to determine whether to apply the constructor DVs to the arguments, which is distinct from having done a full pass through the full DVs replacement stack.

Answer (score 7):

This has everything to do with a special bit called `ValidQ` that is used all over the place in Mathematica. `Replace` by dint of its scanning and likely unpacking of some array of bytes forces a copy of the expression and thus removes this bit.

Just to check that this is the issue:

```
CompiledFunction // FormatValues // Keys

{HoldPattern[
  MakeBoxes[ElisionsDump`cf : CompiledFunction[BoxForm`args__], 
    BoxForm`fmt_] /; 
   BoxForm`UseIcons && 
    System`Private`ValidQ[Unevaluated[ElisionsDump`cf]]]}
```

We can see it is indeed checking for `ValidQ`.

Here's another example:

```
Extract[
 Replace[Hold[Evaluate[comp]], {Hold[x_] :> x}, Infinity], 
 1, 
 System`Private`HoldValidQ
 ]

False
```

We can also use this to make invalid input behave like a `CompiledFunction`:

```
System`Private`HoldSetValid[
   CompiledFunction["asdasdasd", "asdasdasd", "asdasdasd", 
    "asdasdasd", "asdasdasd", "asdasdasd", "asdasdasd", "asdasdasd"]]@
  1;

CompiledFunction::cfct: Number of arguments 1 does not match the length 8314036833820636001 of the argument template.
```

It actually thinks that's a `CompiledFunction` because of this bit. It's powerful.

This is also one of those sneaky places where the object-oriented nature of Mathematica's implementation sneaks through, too:

```
Replace[Hold[Evaluate[comp]], {}, Infinity] === Hold[Evaluate@comp]

True
```

But one isn't `ValidQ` and the other is.

Answer (score 3):

`Replace[x, ..., All]` *is* documented. See section "Details and Options" in the documentation of `Replace`.

There we read that `Infinity` is equivalent to level spec `{1, Infinity}` so that the head of the expression is ignored. *So in your example, just no replacement is happening.*

However, `All` is equivalent to level spec `{0, Infinity}`, taking care also if the head of the expression.

But tell me: Why do you not use `ReplaceAll` with the very nice postfix syntax `/.` in the first place?

```
Hold[Evaluate[comp]] /. Hold[x_] :> x
```

Comment: Ah of course, I read that before but forgot about it. For some reason it's not documented for `Cases`, where the use is the same. But although using `ReplaceAll` instead (I don't think I had a particular reason not to) avoids the unpacking, I would like to know what's going on with that.

Comment: @Jansen `ReplaceAll` never gets below depth `0` and hence the internal expression never gets invalidated and remains in its original state and hence retains its bits marking it as valid.