# Is it possible to make your own output format that uses the "Data not in notebook. Store now" mechanism?

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, boxes

Several functions in WL have a custom elided typesetting form that does not automatically embed large amounts of data into the notebook but presents you with the option to do so if you wish. `SparseArray` is a good example of this:

```
SparseArray[RandomInteger[1, 10^8]]
```

> [image]

You can make objects like these with `` BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox `` as explained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79891/43522), but sometimes the rigid form of `ArrangeSummaryBox` is insufficient for what you want to do. Is there a way to "hijack" this mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time reverse-engineering the `ArrangeSummaryBox` code and came up with the function [`AddCustomTypesetting`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AddCustomTypesetting/). It's easy to use and automatically incorporates the delayed embedding button if the expression is larger than a certain limit (given by `$NotebookInlineStorageLimit`). Consider this example from the Neat Examples section:

```
myObj[assoc_?AssociationQ][key_String] := assoc[key];
myObj[assoc_?AssociationQ][fun_] := fun@assoc;

ResourceFunction["AddCustomTypesetting"][
 myObj[_?AssociationQ], Function[{obj},
  RawBoxes @ Cell[
     BoxData @ ToBoxes @ Row[{
        "myObj", "[", "\[LeftAssociation]",
        Panel @ Grid[{
           {"Length:", obj[Length]},
           {"Keys:", Multicolumn[obj[Keys], 4]},
           {"ByteCount:", obj[ByteCount]}
           }, Alignment -> Left],
        "\[RightAssociation]", "]"
        }],
    ShowStringCharacters -> False
    ]
  ]
 ]

myObj[<|"a" -> RandomReal[1, 10], "b" -> 2|>]
myObj[<|"a" -> RandomReal[1, 10^6], "b" -> 2|>]
```

> [image]

I tend to tinker a bit with functions like these. The latest version can always be found [here](https://github.com/ssmit1986/FunctionRepositoryFunctions/blob/main/FunctionRepo/Kernel/AddCustomTypesetting.wl) on GH. The current version (that I will push to `ResourceFunction["AddCustomTypesetting"]` soon) will also allow you to remove the typesetting rule again with:

```
AddCustomTypesetting[myObj[_?AssociationQ], None]
```